# Vue.js: progress upload doesn't render in view

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to make an uploader component in Vuejs + Firebase Storage. The method works fine, but I can't get to show the percent uploaded in the view. Here my code:

```
<template>

  <div>
    <input type="file" multiple accept="image/*" @change="detectFiles($event.target.files)">
    <div>{{progressUpload}}</div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>

import { storage } from '../firebase'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      progressUpload: 0,
      file: File,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    detectFiles (fileList) {
      Array.from(Array(fileList.length).keys()).map( x => {
        this.upload(fileList[x])
      })
    },
    upload (file) {
      let uploadTask = storage.ref('imagenes/articulos').put(file);

      uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot) {
        this.progressUpload = Math.floor(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100);
      })

      uploadTask.then(() => {
        console.info('File uploaded!');
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Writing {{ progressUpload }} in the HTML template, doesn't show nothing. But in the console, the result is logged perfectly. The file is uploaded properly

Comment: Can you create a complete example? It's hard to tell with just some of the code.

Comment: Did the file uploaded successfully? If possible please show your template code to see how your flow of uploading works.

Comment: Ok, I've added the template code to my example.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution. I had to add the uploadProgress calculation into a watcher that returns the new value of the upload task async method. So, my script has been as follows:

```
<script>

import { storage } from '../firebase'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      progressUpload: 0,
      file: File,
      uploadTask: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    detectFiles (fileList) {
      Array.from(Array(fileList.length).keys()).map( x => {
        this.upload(fileList[x])
      })
    },
    upload (file) {
      this.uploadTask = storage.ref('imagenes/articulos').put(file);

      this.uploadTask.then(() => {
        console.info('Archivo guardado correctamente');
      })
    }
  },
  watch: {
    uploadTask: function() {
      this.uploadTask.on('state_changed', sp => {
        this.progressUpload = Math.floor(sp.bytesTransferred / sp.totalBytes * 100)
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```